# I'm trying to replace NaN values in my Dataframe, with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_hitter['salary'] = df_hitter.where((df_hitter['salary'].isnull()) & (df_hitter['year'] == 2019), axis=1).replace(np.nan, 500000)
```

This line of code above works, I was wondering if theirs a more efficient way, like lambda function or for loop.

For example, if the year is 2005 and salary is a nan I would like to replace it with 200k, if the year is year 2010 and salary is nan I would like to replace it with 275k etc...

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
salary_dict = {2019:500000, 2005:200000, 2010:275000}

df['salary'] = df['salary'].fillna(df['year'].map(salary_dict))
```